# How to add comment as a link in word add-ins?

Tags: plugins, office-js, openxml, docx

I am creating a word application and in that, I Have to add a new comment on the selected text but from the custom task pane. For adding a link I use Rich Text Box and for convert HTML to OOXML I use the "org.docx4j" package in C#. This package returns OOXML format but when I tried with **a hyperlink** and **unordered list**.

Flow:
Call of ajax from office.js file to C# API with HTML body and it returns us an OOXML and add that as comment text and display proper text.

If anyone has an idea please let me know it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a comments on a selected text, please refer to Word JS API [Range.InsertOoxml()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#insertOoxml_ooxml__insertLocation_).
As for adding comments as a link, there is no workaround till now. Please make sure to add your request or vote for an existing on in our [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word).